# Implementing an optimization algorithm in WL

Tags: mathematical-optimization, matlab, searching, functional

I am trying to implement the Jaya optimization algorithm ([Jaya](https://sites.google.com/site/jayaalgorithm/)). This is a flowchart from the Author 's webpage showing the details of the Algorithm.
[image]

Note that there is a typo in the equation in the above figure. It should be:

X'j,k,i = Xj,k,i + r1,j,i (Xj,best,i - │Xj,k,i│) - r2,j,i (Xj,worst,i - │Xj,k,i│)

I have implemented it in the Wolfram Language (WL) as follows:

**Setting the parameters**

```
lb = -10; ub = 10; n (*pop size*)= 4; d (*dimension*)= 2; fn (* function number*)= 1;
```

**Initializing the population**

```
x = RandomReal[{lb, ub}, {n, d + 1}];
```

**Calculating the objective function for each individual**

```
Table[x[[i, -1]] = f[x[[i, 1 ;; -2]], fn], {i, 1, n}]; (* f is the objective function. I am using the last element of each solution to store its objective function *)
```

**The Jaya update equation**

```
update[y_] := Module[{z},

z = y + RandomReal[{0, 1}, d] (x[[minIndex, 1 ;; -2]] - Abs[y]) - RandomReal[{0, 1}, d] (x[[maxIndex, 1 ;; -2]] - Abs[y]);

Map[If[# < lb, lb, If[# > ub, ub, #]] &, z]];
```

**One iteration of Jaya**

```
jaya[x_] := Module[{y, fy},

minIndex = First[Ordering[x[[All, -1]], 1]];

maxIndex = First[Ordering[x[[All, -1]], -1]];

y = Map[update, x[[All, 1 ;; -2]]];

fy = Table[f[y[[i, All]], fn], {i, 1, n}];

y = MapThread[Append, {y, fy}];

MapThread[(If[#1[[-1]] <= #2[[-1]], #1, #2]) &, {x, y}]

]
```

**Repeating the update**

```
Timing[Min[Nest[jaya, x, 1000] [[All, -1]]]]
```

The results when applied to the Sphere function (shown below) are not close to the Matlab implementation of the same Algorithm for the same setting and on the same function.

```
f[x_, 1] := Total[x^2] (* The Sphere function *)
```

In addition, the WL implementation is much slower than Matlab even after using Parallelize, ParallelTable, etc.

Please advice. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please format your code properly inside code blocks ``` ``` . You've got some syntax errors early on which look like they should be comments e.g (pop size) should be a comment `(* popsize *)` ?

Comment: I have edit the post to properly format the code. Thanks!

Comment: One of the problematic point is `Append` - this is very slow operation for iterative process. Switch to usage of `Join` or something else. Additionally, you can change the `jaya[x_]` and `update[x_]` to the pure function style. Like `jaya=Module[{x=#,..},..]&` It will add the performance too.

Comment: Please add cross-post links between this and the Wolfram Community post.

Comment: Thank you so much Rom38. I really appreciate your valuable feedback. I will do that to improve the performance. But do you think the implementation is correct given that for the same settings Matlab is giving me much better results?

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2353990).

Answer (score 1):

I managed finally to make a faster and correct version for Jaya:

```
jaya[fun_, l_, u_, d_, popsize_] := 
 Block[{x, f, best, worst, bestX, worstX, xn, fn, r1, r2},
  x = RandomReal[{l, u}, {popsize, d}];
  f = fun /@ x;
  Do[
   best = x[[First@Ordering[f, 1]]];
   worst = x[[First@Ordering[f, -1]]];
   bestX = Table[best, popsize];
   worstX = Table[worst, popsize];
   r1 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {popsize, d}];
   r2 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {popsize, d}];
   xn = x + r1*(bestX - Abs[x]) - r2*(worstX - Abs[x]);
   xn = Map[If[# > u, u, If[# < l, l, #]] &, xn, {2}];
   fn = Map[fun, xn];
   Do[
    If[f[[i]] >= fn[[i]], {x[[i]], f[[i]]} = {xn[[i]], fn[[i]]}];
    , {i, Length[x]}];
   , {2000}];
  Min[f]
  ]
```

I call it using:

```
sphere = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, Total[x^2]];
AbsoluteTiming[jaya[sphere, -100., 100., 10., 50.]]
```

However, it is 4 times slower than my Matlab implementation (even when I replace the outer `Do` loop with `Nest` -- it becomes slightly slower).

Is there a way to make the code faster? The `Compile` does not work with me.